# Integration of analytics code to Google AMP project

Tags: analytics, amp-html

I am looking forward to integrate my analytics URL to AMP page.
As i see on AMP analytics page we can provide our URL which will collect data but this URL needs to be integrated and approved by Google.
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/ads/amp-analytics
I could not find any related document for this process.

Could you please provide me details for same.

Thanks
Viren

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this [tutorial](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2015/12/08/google-analytics-using-amp/) if this is the one that you need. This tutorial can help you to implement Google Analytics using AMP. It has sample code that you can copy to know how to do it.

For more information, you can check this another [tutorial](http://content.infotrustllc.com/using-google-analytics-accelerated-mobile-pages-amp/) about Using Google Analytics for Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP).

This tutorial has a guide/steps on how to set up AMP with Google Analytics

Comment: we are not using google analytics. We have in house analytics engine. So we are trying to plug it in AMP for tracking as we do it on other pages for our site.